# Android APK file does not connect to server through network : PhoneGap Build

Tags: android, cordova, apk

I'm currently developing an application using PhoneGap in Eclipse. One of the features of the app is that it connects to a remote server through the network. In eclipse, when I run the project as an 'Android Application' directly on the device, everything works perfectly and the device successfully connects to the remote server. This I guess is the 'Debug' build that eclipse offers.
I then go on to create an APK file for the project through PhoneGap's site... I install the APK on the device and when I try to connect, it does not work. The app just hangs when I click on the connect button and does nothing. 
I check the debug build and everything works again like a charm. Can someone please tell me what I'm missing ? Do I need to sign the APK file that I'm creating on the PhoneGap site ? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can put

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.package">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

 <application>
 ...
 </application>
</manifest>
```